# Perl convert image to base64

Tags: perl

I am using a service to send a picture to a server and they require the image be converted to base64 format before it is sent. I tried MIME::Base64 with this code:

```
use MIME::Base64 ();

open (IMAGE, "C:\\wamp\\www\\image.png") or die "$!";

$base64_string = IMAGE;
$encoded = encode_base64($base64_string);
print "Encode $encoded";
```

and got this error message

`Undefined subroutine &mqin::encode_base64 called at line 6.`

Comment: Backslashes have special meaning inside double quotes. You either want to use single quotes (`'C:\wamp\www\image.png'`), escape the backslashes with more backslashes (`"C:\\wamp\\www\\image.png"`), or just use forward slashes (it's OK, really): `"C:/wamp/www/image.png"`.

Comment: There seems to be a problem with Mime::Base64 module on Windows (at least with ActiveState perl 5.8.8) - and yes, I have tried to import that subroutine with `use Mime::Base64 qw(decode_base64)`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you specify an empty import list, like this:

```
use MIME::Base64 ();
```

You get no imports. That means that the function name `encode_base64` will not be imported into the caller's namespace.  You can either allow for the import to happen, or fully qualify the function name by referring to the package it lives in explicitly when you call it.

To import, change that line to:

```
use MIME::Base64;
```

The `()` parens are specifying that MIME::Base64 exports nothing to your namespace.  The default behavior (without the parens) is to export `encode_base64` and `decode_base64`.  By using empty parenthesis in your import list you are overriding the convenient default behavior of importing those two function names.  If you really don't want those functions polluting your `main` namespace you could retain your original `use MIME::Base64 ()` line, and then fully-qualify your subroutine call:

```
$encoded = MIME::Base64::encode_base64($base64_string);
```

But it's a whole lot easier, and probably satisfactory to just allow the default export list to be processed by removing the parenthesis from your `use` line.

Alternatively, you can specify exactly what to import:

```
use MIME::Base64 ('encode_base64');
```

This will import only the `encode_base64` function, but will not import `decode_base64`, thereby minimizing namespace pollution.

**Update** You're also not reading the file.  This line:

```
$base64_string = IMAGE;
```

...should be updated like this:

```
$raw_string = do{ local $/ = undef; <IMAGE>; };
$encoded = encode_base64( $raw_string );
```

That problem would have been caught more verbosely if you had `use strict 'subs'` in effect.  The problem is that "`IMAGE`" by itself is just a bareword, and Perl thinks it's a subroutine call.  The angle brackets, "`<>`" are the common way of reading from a filehandle.  The "`local $/ = undef`" part is just a means of ensuring that you slurp the entire file, not just until the first sequence that looks like a "\n" to Perl.

**Update2:** And as MOB points out, you either need to be escaping the backslashes in your path, or use forward slashes.  Perl doesn't mind, even on Win32.  Of course since you're taking the wise step of using `or die $!` on your `open`, you've already discovered this mistake.

Comment: now the decoded is the text "IMAGE" (really need no decoding, I just want to select an image from my directory and convert to base 64)

Comment: Please note that at least on Windows you have to use `binmode(filehandle)`, otherwise the Base64 output generated from binary file contents will be wrong (actually observed converting a zip file to Base64)

Answer (score 2):

A short Base64 encoder program:

```
# to_base64.pl
use MIME::Base64 qw(encode_base64);

open (IMAGE, $ARGV[0]) || die "$!";
binmode(IMAGE);
local $/;
my $file_contents = <IMAGE>;
close IMAGE;
open (B64, ">$ARGV[0].b64") || die $!;
print B64 encode_base64($file_contents);
close B64;
print "output file is $ARGV[0].b64\n";
```

use it with this command line:

```
perl to_base64.pl image_file.jpg
```

It writes a file named `image_file.jpg.b64` containing the Base64-encoded input file.

To decode Base64, you might use this script:

```
# decode_base64.pl
use MIME::Base64 qw(decode_base64);

open (B64, $ARGV[0]) || die "$!";
local $/;
my $base64_string = <B64>;
close B64;
my $filename;
if ($ARGV[0] =~ /.\.b64$/i) {
    $filename = substr($ARGV[0], 0, length($ARGV[0]) - 4);
}
else {
    $filename = "$ARGV[0].bin";
}
open (IMAGE, ">$filename") || die $!;
binmode(IMAGE);
print IMAGE decode_base64($base64_string);
close IMAGE;
print "output file is $filename\n";
```

Call it using this command line:

```
perl decode_base64.pl my_base64_file.b64
```

If the filename supplied as parameter to this script ends with `.b64` these trailing 4 characters will be removed: `image_file.jpg.b64` => `image_file.jpg`. Otherwise, the script will add `.bin`to the input file name to get an output file name.